# List commits of a specific merge-commit - children only

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

How can I list the commits of a specific merge-commit 845884.

Here, for instance, I only want commits 1, 2, 3 and **only them**

```
*   845884... Merged branch xxxx
|\
| * 68daa7... commit 3
* | a58ec2... commit from master
| |
| * 87da50... commit 2
| |
| * 5e62f9... commit 1
* | 766e1b... commit from master
|/
* 4b8f227
```

Comment: you could say `git log a58ec2..68daa7` that will only list those revisions.... but that is so simple that I wonder if you are asking for a concept deeper than that?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work... an interval will give all commits...

Comment: So, if you are looking to output only commits 1,2, and 3, does something like this work for you? `git log $(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P | awk '{print $(NF)}')...$(git merge-base --octopus $(git log -1 --merges --pretty=format:%P)) --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`

Comment: Nice, but doesn't seem to work, Get all

Comment: @Stef, with that command, which commits are missing?

Comment: I get all the commits even them below 4b8f227

Comment: Huh, that's weird, I tried to re-create the history you've shown and it works. What happens if you add the `--boundary` option at the end?

Comment: Sorry, I still have the commits of the master... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222556/discussion-between-mnestorov-and-stef).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
git log --oneline --graph <commitId>^..<commitId>
```

If you want to exclude the merge commit itself :

```
git log --oneline --graph <commitId>^..<commitId>^2
```

Comment: re-reading the comments, this answer is exactly the same as @eftshift0's. I think the OP didn't try to type it, because it would have given him what he wanted.

Comment: Yes, my mistake I took the merge-commit as first item... Thanks you to @mnestorov too...